# Conditional loading of ViewControllers stuck at initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a user's session with NSUserDefaults, if a user is logged in, I will set the NSUserDefaults to true and vice versa. However, my user is perpetually stuck on the Login Page even if the correct credentials are entered. How can I fix it?

**LoginViewController code**

```
func handlingAuthentication(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = notification.object as! NSDictionary
    let errorFound = dict["error"]
    let errorMessage = dict["message"]
    print(errorFound)

    if(errorFound){
         //initialize Alert Controller
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication error", message: errorMessage?.string, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        //Initialize Actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default){
                (action) -> Void in
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

        //Add Actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        //Present Alert Controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

    }

}
```

This is where I call the method *handlingAuthentication* in LoginViewController

```
@IBAction func loginBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
let loginobj = Login(userName : self.usernameField.text!, passWord : self.pwdField.text!)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.handlingAuthentication(_:)), name:"errorPresent", object: nil)
loginobj.getRequest()
}
```

**HomeViewController code**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("IsUserLoggedIn")
    if(!isUserLoggedIn){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginVC", sender: self)
    }
}

@IBAction func logoutBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Comment: handlingAuthentication how you call this method

Comment: Hi @PKT I called my method in my LoginViewController (updated my post to show this)

Comment: please give line where it get stuck

Comment: self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
that is login vc right ? if yes then from where it presented

Comment: check your segue `toLoginVC`, check whether it is present or push or anything else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different keys:

Since you are storing on the key "isUserLoggedIn"

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
```

isUserLoggedIn will always be false because you are getting a different key "IsUserLoggedIn"

```
let isUserLoggedIn = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("IsUserLoggedIn")
```